# How to format a number string in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

In C#

I have a processing time number data column in the database which is in in this format "###" or "##" ( eg: "813" or "67")

When I bind it to the grid view I wanted to display it in this format "0.###" (eg: "0.813" or "0.067")

I tried using {0:0.000} and other formatings. But none seem to work. Can anyone tell me how to write the format string?

Comment: An old question, but I'm surprised no-one has yet suggested using the Custom "," specifier, which can be used as a number scaling specifier to achieve what you want.  See answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You should really multiply it by .001 before displaying it, then you can use the normal `{0:0.000}` format string.

If, for some reason, that's not possible - you can use a format string of `{0:0\\.000}` which uses the "." not as a decimal separator, but as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable HTML encoding on that column for the format string to take effect.

[Further Reading](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2005/10/31/429090.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Nice post, it really helped.  But better to do it this way:

```
try
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (((DataRowView)(e.Row.DataItem))["Columnname"].ToString().Equals("Total", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            e.Row.Font.Bold = true;
            //-----or ant thing you want to do------
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using [the "," Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), which can be used as a number scaling specifier:

> Number scaling specifier: If one or more commas are specified immediately to the left of the explicit or implicit decimal point, the number to be formatted is divided by 1000 for each comma.

In your example, the format string `{0:0,.000}` can be used to format 813 as `0.813`.

Two commas will scale by 1,000,000, e.g. `{0:0,,.0M}` will format 1753456 as `1.8M`.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you can't change the value before you bind it to the grid, you can handle the RowDataBound event and divide the number by 1000 before displaying it.

```
// Handle the grid's RowDataBound event
MyGridView.RowDataBound += new GridViewRowEventHandler(MyGridView_RowDataBound);

// Set the value to x / 1000 in the RowDataBound event
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound( object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e )
{
    if( e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow )
      return;

    // Cast e.Row.DataItem to whatever type you're binding to
    BindingObject bindingObject = (BindingObject)e.Row.DataItem;

    // Set the text of the correct column.  Replace 0 with the position of the correct column
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = bindingObject.ProcessingTime / 1000M;
}
```

Comment: Should you not be dividing by 1000 ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.  I guess I wasn't worried about that particular part.

Answer (score 0):

So are you looking for something like this?

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", test/1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
GridView.DataSource = .... 

BoundField total = new BoundField();
total.DataField = "Total";
total.HeaderText = "Total Amount";
total.DataFormatString = "{0:C}";
donations.Columns.Add(total);

......
```